# How many background workers can I use?

Tags: multithreading, backgroundworker

How many background workers can I use? Threads? etc.

Comment: 42? This is not a real question.

Comment: Do you mean how many threads can you have in one process?

Comment: This is a dupe of this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145312/maximum-number-of-threads-in-a-net-app

Comment: dupe of this one as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198907/can-i-use-too-many-background-worker-threads

Comment: @Ken White: Not helpful... please explain
@skwllsp: Yes
@Andy: That didn't pop up when I searched
@Sanjeevakumar Hiremath: Didn't catch my eye

Comment: @Storm: [42](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=42). "The Almighty Answer to the Meaning of Life, the Universe, and Everything."

Comment: I find the question perfectly valid, the fact that others in the past had asked similar ones shows that this is not the first time somebody wonders about this.

Comment: @edalorzo: That would make this a duplicate then, wouldn't it? I'm sorry, but "How fast will a plane go?" isn't an answerable question without a lot more information (what kind of plane, what kind of engine, what altitude, etc.).

Comment: @Ken White: I understood the reference. Your answer was simply not helpful. If anyone needed more information they could have said so - I had no idea that my question was not enough to go off of.

Answer (score 3):

Tha maximum number of threads you can create is only bounded by the resources that you have.

This could be the question asked in:

- [Maximum number of threads per
  process in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344203/maximum-number-of-threads-per-process-in-linux)
- [What's the maximum number of threads
  in Windows Server 2003?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481900/whats-the-maximum-number-of-threads-in-windows-server-2003)

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your hardware/software configuration and your use cases.

Comment: This is not an answer, any more than this was a question to answer. (Point being: Please don't answer non-questions. It encourages clutter in the form of other non-questions.) You should delete it before you start collecting downvotes.